# C# nhibernate global search

Tags: nhibernate, c#-4.0, fluent-nhibernate

I have a system which will have about 6 different entities in the domain.
This is a C# winforms app with using Nhibernate. MSSql server. +- 5-10 users.

One of the feature requests is to have a single search bar whereby the user can type and search all of these entities with "Google like" flexibility (i.e. unstructured).
The best method i can think of implementing is to include a clob field on every domain object that also holds text of every field the object represents. my global search just does a like search on the clob field.

This just seems like
1. a mission to maintain (i.e. every object fields needs to be stored inside the clob field and updated with every change)
2. may scale terribly. as the system grows I am sure a LIKE search will get slower and slower causing system strain.

The system isnt going to be massive. I would be surprised if a single table stores more than 10,000 records but I dont like banking on that.

I have read about projects like Lucene.NET which work by indexing a dataset, but then the search will never be "live" but rather a search on the last index.

How have others managed to tackle this one?

Thanks!!

Comment: [NHibernate Search](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHSR) seems to fit the bill (see [Ayende's post](http://ayende.com/blog/3992/nhibernate-search)), I'll be trying that myself soon as well. It's based on Lucene.NET and offers (supposedly) fast full-text searching.

Comment: Does the user need to be able to search absolutely everything?  Does every search need to be 100% up to date, could it be 5/10 mins out of date?

Comment: Yep, NHibernate Search is the bridge you need. It creates/updates index entries whenever you insert/update/delete your entities, so the results would be up to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a *full-text search* solution. Like I mentioned in my comment, what seems to fit the bill for your situation is [NHibernate Search](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NHSR), see also [Ayende @ Rahien's post](http://ayende.com/blog/3992/nhibernate-search) on the subject.